# OpenCV Python Video playback - How to set the right delay for cv2.waitKey()

Tags: python, opencv, video, delay, frame-rate

I used the following code to capture a video file, flip it and save it.

```
#To save a Video File

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This program saves the output as output.avi

Now, to playback the video file I used the following program

```
#Playing Video from File

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')

print cap.get(5) #to display frame rate of video
#print cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)

while(cap.isOpened()): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert to grayscale

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This program plays the video file output.avi saved from the first program. The thing is, this video appears fast forward. So, I tried changing the delay value for cv2.waitKey(). The video looked fine when I put 100. How do I know which value to put there? Should it be related to the frame rate? I checked the frame rate of output.avi (see line cap.get(5) in second program) and got 20. But if I use 20 as delay for cv2.waitKey() the video is still too fast.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7):

> The function `cv.waitKey([, delay])` waits for a key event infinitely
>   (when `delay <= 0`) or for `delay` milliseconds, when it is positive.

If the FPS is equal to 20, then you should wait 0,05 seconds between displaying the consecutive frames. So just put `waitKey(50)` after `imshow()` in order to have the desired speed for the playback.

Comment: so should the formula be (1 / fpm) * 1000 ?

Comment: or actually, maybe it has to be an integer, so int( (1 / int(fps)) * 1000)

Comment: @Kornel, how do I know what the FPS is?

Comment: fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, I have tried all sorts of tricks with setting the cv2.waitKey() delay time and they have all failed. What I have found to work is to try something like:`key = cv2.waitKey(1)` inside of your while(cap.isOpened()) like so:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret==True:
      key = cv2.waitKey(1)
      frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

      # write the flipped frame
      out.write(frame)

      cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
      if key & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 2):

put `waitKey(60)` after `imshow()` and it will be displayed at normal speed.